# Not able to train on facebook messenger smiley ":)"

Tags: dialogflow-es, emoji

I am trying to train my dialogflow app on smileys such as ":)" and ":(", but it seems like dialogflow does not accept these symbols. I am able to train dialogflow on the real emojies (the ones they become in facebook messenger). However, when users are writing ":)" (which becomes a smiley), it does not work.

It seems like when writing ":)" that become a smiley, it is a different symbol for the smiley than when selecting the smiley from the facebook emoji overview. How can I find out what the difference is, and train dialogflow to know both these symbols?

Comment: how are training on real emojies?

Comment: i just tried to train an intent with `:)` `:(` and it worked without any issue

Comment: Training on real emojies works fine. I copy emojies from this url: http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: i think `:)` becomes `U+1F642` or something similar, so you need to train it on this data as well. you should check the incoming request to dialogflow what exactly you are getting.